# Sweep line algorithm for circle intersection, represent circle into two halves

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry, sweep-line

I am trying to develop sweep line algorithm for given list of circles. by checking different sources I am able to understand the algorithm .

here are the links that i am referring ,

1. http://www.stolerman.net/studies/cs623/cs623_winter_2012_sol2.pdf
2. [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15451-f17/lectures/lec21-sweepline.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15451-f17/lectures/lec21-sweepline.pdf)

As the solution in given links says that We need to represent the circle in two halves because every sweep line intersect a given circle at most two point at any given time.

I am not able to understand how can we represent any circle in two halves e.g., bottom half and top half . It will be great help if someone can explain the data structure to represent a circle into two halves and how the ordering will be defined for semicircles in binary search tree ?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you linked to uses the fact that, if you have two opposite points on a circle, the segment between them uniquely defines a circle, and that segment is a diameter of the circle.
Hence, if you keep a list of all rightmost and leftmost points for all your circle, you will have a representation of all your circles.

More generally, you just need to make sure that the two points you are keeping for each circle make a diameter that is perpendicular to the sweep line you are using in the algorithm.

Depending on what the expected input for the algorithm is, you will need to translate that representation into those two points, but then, with a list of couple of points: `[(p1, p2), ..., (p_{2n-1}, p_{2n})]` where you have `n` circles.

Comment: if we create semi circles in this way how to make sure which one is top half and other one is bottom half

Comment: @optional this is made by deciding that the arc is drawn clockwise from first point to the second. So if first point is to the left then semicircle goes over the line, and if the first point is to the right then it is under the line.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing a circle in the tree, you can store two half-circles. They result from splitting the circle so that the sweep-line meets a half-circle only once. Whether you indeed store two half circles, or two references to the same circle with a way to tell which half is a matter of ease of implementation.

Beware that two half-circles may intersect even if the segments that join the same endpoints do not intersect.

[image]

Comment: : i am not able to decode that how to represent (programatically )a circle into two semi circle or  two references to the same circle with a way to tell which half is a matter of ease of implementation..

Comment: @optional: just create two half-circles then.

Comment: please help to create them programatically and to decode them as top half and bottom half

Comment: @optional: sorry, this site is not a free coding factory.